# View.OnFocusChangeListener for HorizonalScrolView?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, focuslistener

Does any one have idea how `View.OnFocusChangeListener` work for `HorizontalScrollView`?

I want basicaaly focus event for it's child view ?

any one have idea about it?

Comment: Is there any itemListener available for HorScrollView like we have for ListView?

Comment: what is the child view of your HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: @PratikSharma it's linear layout..which add other linearlayout as an child at runtime...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your problem with following way :

```
view1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);

view1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "view1 Got Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "view1 Lost Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        });
```

But this is not firing anything, means linear layout is not able to get and lost focus.

So, I tried with setOnClickListener listener in this way :

```
view1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);

view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "view1 Got Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And it works fine.

So, it may be helpful to you to set your logic from your linear layout's setOnClickListener event.

Let me know if you find any confusion or need more help from me.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your support...but how your solution will support for focus on child...?

Comment: you can add ClickListener for all your child view's so whenever user get focus/click there it will fire.  Even though your child added dynamically you can set ClickListeners for the same also.

Comment: I need to dig more on this...because everytime i create child linearlayout and make it null once it added in parent layout....btw thanks for your support :)

Comment: Let me know if you need any kind of help required from me. Btw if my solution is helpful to you somehow then you can accept that too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Pratik...stl stuck with my solution..is it possible for you to share demo sample(btw I accept your comment :)).

Comment: Hi @Shubh . It will be somewhat difficult to make demo right now. It will be good if you send your code to me with some details to follow then I will definitely check that and try to solve that.